# Is this a valid workaround to the constructor issue with mixins?

Tags: c++, constructor, decorator, mixins

As I understand there is a problem with mixins where, if you want to use something other than a no-arg constructor, the objects you use your mixin on will either have to have a common constructor signature or you have to use initializer methods in the classes you want to use the mixin with.

This seems to be kind of a workaround, though I'm not sure if there are situations in which it would fail. It makes the mixin work more like a decorator, but it removes the need for the common interface that the decorators inherit from. I guess another problem is that the syntax might get clunky?

Just want to know if there is anything horribly dangerous about this. I also would like to know if I, being a not so smart programmer, have misunderstood this problem with mixins.

Edit: this appears to be a better formulation.

```
class Base
{
protected:
    std::string name;
public:
    Base()
    {
        name = "no arg constructor";
    }
    Base(std::string n)
    {
        name = n;
    }

    virtual void doSomething()
    {
        cout << name << "\n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
private:
    int x;
public:

    Derived(std::string n, int i) : Base(n)
    {
        x = i;
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        cout << "x = " << x << "\t";
        Base::doSomething();
    }
};

template <class T>
class Decorator : public T
{
public:
    Decorator(const T& initializer) : T(initializer)
    {
        //*static_cast< T* >(this) = *initializer;
        //delete initializer;
    }
};

void method(Base& b)
{
    b.doSomething();
}

int main()
{
    Base b;
    Decorator<Base> d1(b);
    Decorator<Base> d2(Base("decorated"));
    Decorator<Derived> d3(Derived("derived", 777));

    method(d1);
    method(d2);
    method(d3);

    return 0;
}
```

no arg constructor

decorated

x = 777 derived

Comment: @Martin: what do you mean by legal?

Comment: @Martin: it is not, though I would have used a two phases approach: `T& me = *this; me = *initializer;` because the `static_cast` is unnecessary in this direction.

Comment: @Matthieu: so that behavior >is< undefined? And for my info, can you explain why this is preferable to the static_cast? Type checking?

Comment: Sorry, the behavior is perfectly defined, as far as I can see. I refrain from using casts wherever I can because they may allow things that are undesirable, for example, you could unwittingly write `static_cast<Y*>(this)` (typo) and if `Y` derives from your class or `T` then the cast will silently compile. Since it's unnecessary here, I thus prefer not to cast, so that the compiler knows (and warns me) if an error occurs. It is very much a matter of preference though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You're leaking memory if an exception is thrown during construction,
2. The base class must have a default constructor to be be constructed first and then assigned.

Better do:

```
Decorator(const T& initializer) : T(initializer)
{
}
```

and use:

```
Decorator<Base> d1((Base()));
Decorator<Base> d2(Base("decorated"));
Decorator<Derived> d3(Derived("derived",777));
```

Also in C++0x you can forward perfectly any number of arguments from Decorator's constructor to the base constructor, effectively making the usage as clean as usual:

```
Decorator<Base> d1;
Decorator<Base> d2("decorated");
Decorator<Derived> d3("derived",777);
```

Comment: yes, using the copy constructor seems much nicer. In my inexperience, I didn't really know you could initialize the base class with a copy constructor. Thanks.

Comment: I edited my code. Thanks. So is the information I've been reading just old? Are workarounds like this well known or are people just waiting for C++0x to get all ISO?

Comment: @user487100: you can approximate variadic templates in C++03 by writing constructors with different amount of arguments. You can use preprocessor magic to do it nicely.

Comment: +1 for the copy constructor approach, I'm so immersed in C++0x these days that I forget about the traditional ways :)

Comment: @ybungalobill: I imagine that's a much better solution. Here I suppose you need to construct every object twice.

Comment: @Matthieu: I must be missing the boat on C++0x. That's what I get for not being a computer scientist I guess.

Comment: @user487100: I am no CS myself, and we still use C++03 (and will be for years) at work, but I like to explore at home :)

Comment: @ybungalobill: if you have it available, could you redirect me to some info on emulating variadic templates with the preprocessor?

Comment: @user: see [Boost.Preprocessor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/preprocessor/doc/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

This is the reason why C++0x included the ability to forward, safely, an arbitrary number of elements:

```
template <typename T>
struct Decorator: T
{
  template <typename... Args>
  Decorator(Args&&... args): T(args...) {}
};
```

Which forwards the arguments cleanly. Check it out on [ideone](http://ideone.com/otbio)!

Comment: That's very pretty. Nice ideaone is nice, too!